# ArrayList not deleting properly

Tags: android, arraylist

I have a screen where the user selects items he/she wants deleted, then I store his/her choices into an integer arrayList (based on which positions they clicked on the listView).

I then pass the items that they want deleted to a function where I actually delete them from my hashtable that holds all the information. For some reason though, it's just NOT deleting from the hashtable. I've tested and looked at all the variables I'm using to access the data and they are correct. I'm not sure why it's not removing what I tell it to..

Here is the function:

```
for (Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Deck>> i : listOfDecks.entrySet()) {
                    for (int p = 0; p < i.getValue().size(); p++) {
                        if (i.getValue().get(p).getTitle().equals(deckTitle)) {
                            for (int z = 0; z < deletedItems.size(); z++) {
                                listOfDecks.get(i.getKey()).get(p).getDeck().remove(deletedItems.get(z));

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

deletedItems is the arrayList that holds what the user has selected as their items they want deleted.

Comment: You should add some logging using `Log.i(String tag, String messageText)` to see what it's actually doing, like the value of `deckTitle` and etc... And instead of iterating through every deck, the list of deleted items should contain exactly where the choices are so you need only iterate through that.

Comment: It's going to be a bit hard to determine what the problem is with the code you've given us, but I'd recommend that you check `equals` and `hashCode` are working as expected for the key you're trying to remove. (I.e., if you haven't redefined them, ensure that the return of `deletedItems.get(z)` is actually a key in the map.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I see is that you are calling Deck.remove(int) so you're not removing from a hashtable, but from a deck.

What does this method remove(int) of the class Deck do?.

Comment: Sorry I actually just figured it out. Someone posted a solution a little while ago and then erased it, but it gave me a good idea.
well Deck is an arrayList. And remove is the standard android arrayList remove function. It just removes that position from the arrayList. Problem was every time I erased something, I needed to adjust my arrayList accordingly and decrement it by 1.

Comment: Then maybe you should first get the items to be deleted and then delete them by Object instead than position. Either way, you should post your solution for future reference :)